# X-Editable and Bootstrap datatables

Tags: javascript, html, datatable, x-editable

I've tried with no success to implement x-editable in bootstrap datatables, the reason being when i update an element from x editable, the datatable fails to recognize those changes.. i've tried updating the table, destroying it, hidden tags, but the main problem seems to be that the datatables fails to recognize any change after the initialization..
I add the rows via button click, when they get to the table, i run .editable on those elements. they become editable but the sorting and search of the datatables doesnt work..

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that for performance reasons, Datatables caches the table into memory so actually the DOM table is different from the in-memory table. And when you modify the DOM, it doesn't change the table in-memory.

Therefore, Datatables created a function helper : `invalidate()` that you can apply on a row http://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29.invalidate%28%29 (there is a multiple rows version too).

Or you can still use the function `data()` which is less CPU consuming (recommended).

I would do something like this :

```
$('.xeditable').on('save', function(e, params) {
    var $tr = $(e.target).closest('tr');
    var newValue = params.newValue;
    //If you didn't save the datatable into a var table, you need to call this line :
    //var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    table.row(tr).data(newValue);
    //Or table.row(tr).invalidate(); which should read from the DOM directly
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, i think this is the right path, but when i do cell(td).data(newValue) it destroys the editable, just becomes text .. i'll keep trying other ways to do this

Comment: How do you create your datatable ? Ajax ?

Comment: simple html table, data is inserted trough  table.row.add.. each td   is an <a> tag with my personal .editable class so that after it gets added to the table, i run a function on that <tr> to put every <a> editable

Comment: well i kind of managed to get it working by calling ('#client_process_table').DataTable().rows().invalidate("dom"); eveytime any x editable is edited.. but i believe this is not the best way to do this..